# Graph Decomposition And Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

A *module* in a graph $G$ is a subset $M$ of the vertices such that all the vertices in $M$ have the same neighbourhoods *outside* of $M$. That is, if $v_1, v_2 \in M$ and $x \not\in M$, then we have $v_1x\in E(G)$ iff $v_2x\in E(G)$. They generalise connected components.

[It is known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_decomposition) that every graph who is both connected and whose complement is connected, can be expressed as a union of disjoint, maximal nontrivial modules.

My question is, does the modular decomposition of a graph have any relationship known to the related matrices of a graph, e.g. adjacency matrix, Laplacian etc?

Comment: I think the relation to adjacency matrix is straightforward.

Comment: Well, the adjacency matrix will be in block form: [1, 2, 3, 4] where 1 is a square matrix representing the module, and 2, 3 are constituted of all 0 and all 1 rows and columns respectively.

Comment: But is there anything beyond this, in terms of properties of matrices and vectors that have linear algebraic meaning, etc?